# Run Apostrophe 2 CMS on IIS (IISNode)?

Tags: iisnode, apostrophe-cms

You configure the server and app like the other Node.js based apps on IIS (like in this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170617144643/http://www.galaco.me:80/node-js-on-windows-server-2012/)) and install [ImageMagic](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) (required by Apostrophe CMS). After that, when you running apostrophe app, you may see an error "The configured bundle apostrophe was not found in npm.".

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the apostrophe automatically looking the root module of an app and found IISNode module that wraps the app for running on IIS. For avoiding this you must declare the [root](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/core-server.html#code-root-code) module explicitly in the Apostrophe options:

```
var apos = require('apostrophe')({
    shortName: 'yourappname',
    title: 'yourappname',
    root: module,
    modules: {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer EddieG. Just occurred to me to ask: how hard is it to sniff out the IISNode module and disregard that one when walking the chain of modules? That would make a great pull request.